# What is the code for adding content in Blog template?

Tags: html, templates, blogs, blogspot

Currently I'm learning how to create blog templates for Blogspot. I have created the header successfully but I don't know the exact code for the blog post's.

You can check my blog here: http://somnath0000.blogspot.in/

I was not able to find anything. You can see my code here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>AndroidStarkDevelopers</title>

    <style>
        #header {
     color:white;
     background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/va0xsJD.jpg);
     
}
        h1 {
            line-height:50%;
            margin-top: 0;
            height:24px;
            padding-left:170px;
            padding-top:0px;
            position:relative;
            bottom:88px;
            left:50px;
        }
        p{
            font-size:medium;
        }
        a {
            margin-top: 0;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
body
        {
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-right:80px;
            margin-left:80px;
            background-color: transparent;
        }
</style>
<b:skin><![CDATA[   ]]></b:skin>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <img alt="Android_stark" src="http://i.imgur.com/OW2BuQK.png" style="width:130px;height:130px;padding-top:13px;padding-left:50px;line-height"/>
        <h1>
            <a href="http://www.w3schools.com">
                AndroidStarkDevelopers<br/>
                <p>Nature Of Minon But Work Like Iron Man</p>

            </a>

        </h1>
    </div>
<b:section class='main' id='main' showaddelement='no'><b:widget id='Blog1' locked='true' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog'/></b:section>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help so i can see my blog posts with the current header.

Comment: I can recommend this site for information on how to make Blogger templates: http://code.blogger.com/

Comment: thanks for sharing but i'm really new to html it would be help full if anyone can directly tell me the code for showing blog content

Comment: I think an easier way to go for you would be to lightly modify an already existing theme.

Comment: yeah i thought about that but the thing is i want to learn that's why i'm trying. but i didn't found nothing on internet

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using data-attributes of Blogger. Read about them [here](http://thoughtsomething.blogspot.ru/2009/01/understanding-blogger-template-1.html) and [here](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46995?hl=en).